# Dynamically generated Image Contorls in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to create as an Image control dynamically in WPF application and set the properties of that controls ...like Size,location,color,sizemode 
how can i do it? Give me any Samplecode for that..

Comment: ok ... but i have to create 10 image controls  and then i have to place them in single Application.... now what can i do:

Comment: Please stop asking the same questions repeatedly.  If you want to add more details, you can edit your questions by using the `edit` link above these comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example which I have done which loads in the logo for stack overflow.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var webImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png"));
        var imageControl = new Image();
        imageControl.Source = webImage;
        ContentRoot.Children.Add(imageControl);
    }
}
```

and the xaml...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfExamples.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You'd like to display an image file or stream? Or you're going to create an image control and add it to the window in code?

Comment: i want to create as an Image control dynamically and set the properties of that controls

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx), on MSDN

```
// Create Image Element
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Width = 200;

// Create source
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Water Lilies.jpg");

// To save significant application memory, set the DecodePixelWidth or  
// DecodePixelHeight of the BitmapImage value of the image source to the desired 
// height or width of the rendered image. If you don't do this, the application will 
// cache the image as though it were rendered as its normal size rather then just 
// the size that is displayed.
// Note: In order to preserve aspect ratio, set DecodePixelWidth
// or DecodePixelHeight but not both.
myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
myBitmapImage.EndInit();
//set image source
myImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
```

Comment: ok ... but i have to create 10 image controls and then i have to place them in single Application.... now what can i do